# How to see who else is included in message on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Someone sent me a Facebook message and I replied but some other people I don't know replied too. Is there a list of everyone involved in the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hover your mouse over `xx Others` in `Friend name and xx others` and click on `See All`. It'll show all the people who are added in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android App, if you click on the (i) symbol on the top right hand corner when you are in the group message feed to get to the 'group info' screen, then scroll down and tap on 'members' to see a list.

(i) symbol > members

Comment: As this is [webapps.se], we generally expect solutions to be for the web interface.